# Slow opening of any email after set value for an object on Application_ItemLoad

Tags: vba, outlook, office-automation

Basically I am using below code to run macro after I manually open a specific email. 
The code and macro works ,but I noticed there is a slowness while opening of any email on outlook. 
After many tests, I find out this line is the cause of issue:

```
Set MyItem = Item
```

And this the full code:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Public WithEvents MyItem As Outlook.MailItem

 
Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
       Set MyItem = Item  'This line cause slow opening of any email
    End If
End Sub
 
Private Sub myItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
      If MyItem.Subject = "Test Email" Then
      'Code
      End If
End Sub
```

Kindly How to fix this issue?

Comment: Looks like assigning that code to every email that is loaded has such an impact that it slows down the opening. Probably can't do much against it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ ,I tried to move all the code on `Sub Application_ItemLoad` into `myItem_Open` but the final macro not triggered , without any error raised.

Comment: What is your goal of handling the `ItemLoad` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically I am using below code to run macro after I manually open a specific email.

You may consider using other event handlers in Outlook - for selecting in the `Explorer` window you may try to handle the [SelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selectionchange) event of the `Explorer` class which is fired when the user selects a different or additional Microsoft Outlook item programmatically or by interacting with the user interface. For opening in the separate window you can handle the [NewInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspectors.newinspector) event which is fired whenever a new inspector window is opened, either as a result of user action or through program code. The event occurs after the new Inspector object is created but before the inspector window appears. Also you may handle the [Inspector.Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.activate(even)) event which is fired when an inspector becomes the active window, either as a result of user action or through program code.

If there is a specific reason to use the `ItemLoad` event handler in the code you may continue using the late-binding technology and keep the item defined as object.

Also don't forget to release corresponding objects in the `Unload` event of the `Item`-level events.

Comment: This answer   https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/always-open-email-maximized-window-outlook-vba/   is similar to your code, but more clearer. In fact ,It fixed a lot of my issue and I will post it (after adapted) as my answer.

Comment: The answer was given without any code, so I don't understand what could be clearer there. Please don't forget to mark the answer.

Comment: Also, I had to use `Set oInspector = Nothing` at end of `oInspector_Activate` ,otherwise my final macro will run on infinitive loop.and please consider me as a beginner on outlook programming.